# Restlet - StreamClosedException using StreamingOutput

Tags: java, exception, restlet, truezip

I'm experiencing problems with my Restlet Resource. It uses TrueZip to build a subset of a Zip Archive and allows the user to download it.

```
// Create a Streaming Response Entity.
    final StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(final OutputStream output) {
                ZipBrowser.extract(source, path, output);
        }
    };
    LOGGER.debug("Download of Path {} with the length {} initiated", path, length);
    ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok(stream);
    rb.header(HeaderConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_DISPOSITION, CONDISPOVALUE + fileName);
    rb.header(HeaderConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, length);
    return rb.build();
```

Even though it works I receive an annoying StreamClosedException. This error appears only when I try to download a subset and not the whole Zip Archive:

```
An exception occured writing the responseentity

    sun.net.httpserver.StreamClosedException
    at sun.net.httpserver.ChunkedOutputStream.flush(ChunkedOutputStream.java:156)
    at sun.net.httpserver.PlaceholderOutputStream.flush(ExchangeImpl.java:449)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerCall.writeResponseBody(ServerCall.java:511)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerCall.sendResponse(ServerCall.java:454)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerAdapter.commit(ServerAdapter.java:187)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:144)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpServerHelper$1.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:64)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:80)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:677)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)Unable to send error response

    java.io.IOException: headers already sent

    at sun.net.httpserver.ExchangeImpl.sendResponseHeaders(ExchangeImpl.java:204)
    at sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchangeImpl.sendResponseHeaders(HttpExchangeImpl.java:86)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpExchangeCall.writeResponseHead(HttpExchangeCall.java:148)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerCall.sendResponse(ServerCall.java:450)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerAdapter.commit(ServerAdapter.java:205)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:144)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpServerHelper$1.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:64)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:80)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:677)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by both the zip library and the Restlet Framework trying to close the `OutputStream` once they have finished.

I have experienced this in the past with other libraries  and have managed to eliminate the exception by wrapping the `OutputStream` I pass to the zip library in a class which Overrides `close()` to do nothing.  With all other methods delegated.  This then allows Restlet to close the stream.

So that the line calling the Zip utility in your code becomes:

```
 ZipBrowser.extract(source, path, new WrappedOutputStream(output));
```

Where the `WrappedOutputStream` class is indicated below (delegating methods will need to be added).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class WrappedOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private final OutputStream delegate;

    public WrappedOutputStream(final OutputStream delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        // Do Nothing to allow Restlet to close the underlying stream
    }

    // TODO Delegate other Outpt Stream methods.
}
```

Comment: Great idea! Just tried it out and works. Thanks a lot :-)